# angle bracket in xml value

Tags: xml

How can I put an angle bracket ("<") in my xml attribute?

I'm trying to store an SQL query, but this seems to be illegal.

```
<add key="query" value="SELECT DISTINCT index FROM table WHERE langCode <> 'FR'"/>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`:

```
<add key="query" value="SELECT DISTINCT index FROM table WHERE langCode &lt;&gt; 'FR'"/>
```

Comment: Yep, +1. Actually you don't have to escape the `>`, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: In general, you do have to escape `>` if it is part of a `]]>` string in content (unless it is being used to end a CDATA section, [see specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax)).

Comment: " --> &quot;
' --> &apos;
< --> &lt;
> --> &gt;
& --> &amp;

Comment: I don't think ]]> needs to be escaped if part of an attribute value.