# Specify Angle bracket as pattern value in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way by which I can specify angle bracket as pattern value in `XSD`?

```
<xs:element name="Coords">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:pattern value="<Coord\d+>.*<\/Coord\d+>" />     <!--- WHAT IS THE CORRECT USAGE HERE --->
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Escape it as &lt; or &gt; Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197195/angle-bracket-in-xml-value

Comment: That should be an answer not a comment...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angle bracket in xml value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197195/angle-bracket-in-xml-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now as an answer instead of a comment:

Escape it as `&lt;` or `&gt;`

Also see:

[angle bracket in xml value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197195/angle-bracket-in-xml-value)